# How to implement frequency map of a vector of strings only using stl library

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, stdvector, frequency

Assume I have a vector of words and I want to count for each word occurrences in this vector and then output it to a map with its occurrences number. How do I do it most efficiently using algorithms only in c++?

I have tried already using std::count, but cannot figure out how to count for all words (not only specific one, someone mentioned using std::count_if with lambda function).

```
std::vector<string> words = {"the", "domestic", "cat", "has", "a", "smaller", "skull", "and", "shorter", "bones", "than", "the", "european", "cat", "males", "are", "larger", "than", "females", "a"}
std::cout << std::count (words.begin(), words.end(), "cat") << endl; //outputs 2
```

Comment: What is the topic of the chapter in your C++ textbook where this practice problem is from, or the topic of your C++ class, where this homework assignment was given? There are several possible approaches I can think of, but the wrong solution will probably not give you the full credit.

Comment: *'using algorithms only'* Could you clarify that comment?

Comment: Probably OP's professor just wants them to iterate and insert/update into `std::map<string, int>`, or possibly `std::unordered_map<string, int>`

Comment: Look at your end goal: a `std::map<std::string, int>`. How would you fill in the frequency table for a single-word vector?

Comment: _using algorithms only_: do you mean from `#include <algrorithms>` only? Your requirement is pretty unclear.

Comment: Sorry for making myself unclear. By using algorithms only I mean STL Library as a whole. The point is try to avoid writting own algorithms and use the "more efficient ones" which are part of STL Library.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `std::map<std::string, size_t>` as you already mentioned in your question.

There is no need to use any algorithm. Just initialize the map with elements of the vector using for example the range-based for loop.

For example

```
std::map<std::string, size_t> m;

for ( const auto &word : words )
{
    ++m[word];
}
```

Instead of the range-based for loop you can use standard algorithm `std::for_each` if you like. Something like

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

//...

std::map<std::string, size_t> m;

std::for_each( std::begin( words ), std::end( words ),
               [&m] ( const auto &word )
               {
                   ++m[word];
               } );
```

To output words and their frequencies you also can use the same algorithm `std::for_each` or the range based for loop  as for example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, size_t> m = { { "cat", 2 }, { "european", 1 } };

    for (const auto &[word, frequency] : m)
    {
        std::cout << std::quoted( word ) << ": " << frequency << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';          

    std::for_each( std::begin( m ), std::end( m ),
        []( const auto &p )
        {
            std::cout << std::quoted( p.first ) << ": " << p.second << '\n';
        } );
}
```

The program output is

```
"cat": 2
"european": 1

"cat": 2
"european": 1
```

Comment: Oops--yes. Meant to use an `std::stringstream` there. Sorry.